# How to find MLE of bivariate, 3 parameter function in R

Tags: r, statistics

I need to find the MLE for the 3 parameters in the function below using R (set of random 2 dimensional points for X&Y).

[image]

How would I enter the complex function into R?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for. `dnorm` is the probability density function for normal (defaults to standard normal if mean and sd not supplied). `pnorm` is the cumulative distribution function for normal (also defaults to standard normal if mean and sd not supplied and gives the lower tail area, which is what we want):

```
# Construct function
MLE= function(x, y, mu1, mu2, theta){
  numerator = dnorm(x-mu1)*dnorm(y-mu2)*theta*(1-exp(-theta))*exp(-theta*(pnorm(x-mu1)+pnorm(y-mu2)))
  denominator = (1-exp(-theta)-(1-exp(-theta*pnorm(x-mu1)))*(1-exp(-theta*pnorm(y-mu2))))^2
  result = numerator/denominator
  return(result)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize it was so simple, but after looking at the way you broke it down, it's a lot more intuitive.

Comment: @L.Ugrad Glad that it helps. If you think this answer is what you want, do you mind accepting it?